# Operation from each vector in a 2D tensor on each 2D matrix in a 3D tensor

Tags: tensorflow, tensordot

I have a 2D tensor. I would like to take each vector in that 2D tensor and `tf.tensordot(vector, matrix, axes=1)` to the matrix in a 3D tensor that has the same index in the 3D tensor as the vector does in the 2D tensor.

Essentially, I'd like the same result as I'd get with this for loop, but by doing tensorflow matrix operations rather than numpy and looping:

```
tensor2d = np.array([[1.,1.,1.,0.,0.],
                 [1.,1.,0.,0.,0.]],
                np.float32)

tensor3d = np.array([
    [
        [1., 2., 3.],
        [2., 2., 3.],
        [3., 2., 3.],
        [4., 2., 3.],
        [5., 2., 3.],
    ],
    [
        [1., 2., 3.],
        [2., 2., 3.],
        [3., 2., 3.],
        [4., 2., 3.],
        [5., 2., 3.],
    ]
], np.float32)

results = []

for i in range(len(tensor2d)):
    results.append(np.tensordot(tensor2d[i], tensor3d[i], axes=1))
```

Output of this should be a matrix that looks like this (though types would be different):

`[array([6., 6., 9.], dtype=float32), array([3., 4., 6.], dtype=float32)]`

Answer (score 0):

Ok, the self-found answer boils down to use `tf.math.multiply` and mess around with transposes until the result is the desired shape. Would be great if someone could come up with a more principled answer at some point, but for now, this worked:

```
result = tf.transpose(tf.math.multiply(tensor2d, tensor3d.transpose([2,0,1])), [1,2,0])
```